# Insert Values to Collection issue in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to insert query to collection using **meteorjs**.I did a sample as shown below and get error of when ever execute an insert query.Please see the below code and error and suggest me what to do?

I get this error when execute the below insert query:

```
Error: Method not found [404]
```

```js
var userid = t.find('#userid').value
, firstname = t.find('#fname').value
, lastname = t.find('#lname').value
, bday = t.find('#bday').value
, bmonth = t.find('#bmonth').value
, byear = t.find('#byear').value;

hcare_users.insert({
    userid: userid, 
    firstname : firstname,
    lastname : lastname,
    bday: bday, 
    bmonth : bmonth,
    byear : byear
}, function( error, result) { 
    if ( error ) console.log ( "error ="+ error); //info about what went wrong
    if ( result ) {
        console.log ( "result="+result );//the _id of new object if successful
        $('input[type="text"]').val('');
        //$('input[type="radio"]').val('');
        //$('input[type="date"]').val('');
        alert("Sucessfully Created");
    }                   
});
```

Comment: could you rephrase the question? I can't parse this. What is the error?

Comment: when ever execute the insert query below error will came into sewrver console.Error: Method not found [404] @ Christian Fritz

Comment: did  you define your collection on both client and server side? `hcare_users = new Meteor.Collection('hcare_users')`

Comment: Can you please show the code where you define `hcare_users`?

Comment: hcare_users = new Meteor.Collection('hcare_users') this is my collection name.@Serkan Durusoy

Answer (score -1):

```
hcare_users.insert({
                     userid: userid, 
                     firstname : firstname,
                     lastname : lastname,
                     bday: bday, 
                     bmonth : bmonth,
                     byear : byear,

                      });
```

that's all code? i think you miss something.
or you could use browser's debug mode to check what error on javascript;
if you use chrome. you could call ctrl+shift+i to see the console area.
To check what error message on JS.

Comment: please see above code once and suggest me?.@TimeGuard

Comment: this is not an answer. You should make this a comment.

Comment: if i can comment on question,i will.